# PDF Reader Python

Tags: python-3.x, filereader

I am trying to create a code that can read a PDF file from a folder and extract the data from it, and then put it on an Excel sheet.

I am currently at the beginning stage, trying to extract specific data from the file.

To simplify the process, I am using keywords and loops, but I am not seeing any progress. I am open to ideas and suggestions.

Below, I am sharing the code and files. Thank you!

```
import PyPDF2
import re

with open('sample.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    # Create a PDFReader object
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

    # Extract the text from the PDF file
    text = pdf_reader.pages[0].extract_text()

    # Define a dictionary to store the values
    values = {}

    # Define the keywords and the corresponding keys in the dictionary
    keywords = {"ISIN": "ISIN",
                "Fecha de Registro": "Record Date",
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v35AI.png)                "Fecha Ex Date en USA": "Ex Date",
                "Fecha de Pago": "Pay Date",
                "a pagar por CEDEARs": "Amount in USD to pay by CEDEARs"}

    # Search for the keywords in the text and store the values in the dictionary
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        for keyword, key in keywords.items():
            if keyword in line:
                # Extract the value after the colon
                value = line.split(":")[1].strip()
                # If the key is "Amount in USD to pay by CEDEARs", extract the value using a regular expression
                if key == "Amount in USD to pay by CEDEARs":
                    match = re.search(r"\d+([,.]\d+)?", value)
                    if match:
                        values[key] = match.group(0)
                else:
                    values[key] = value

        # Check if the line contains the words "Bruto - estimado"
        if "Bruto - estimado" in line:
            # Set the value to 7
            values["Marker"] = "7"
            break

    # Rename the "Bruto - estimado" key to "Marker"
    values["Marker"] = values.pop("Bruto - estimado", values.get("Marker"))

    # Print the values
    for key, value in values.items():
        print(key + ":", value)
```

[sample.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV8jz.png)

ISIN: ARDEUT112497
Record Date: 2/5/2023
Ex Date: 28/4/2023
Pay Date: 3/5/2023
Amount in USD to pay by CEDEARs: 1,730000
Marker: 7

However, when I switch to another PDF sample, I am not getting the expected results:
[sample2.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdjt3.png)

Record Date:
ISIN: CUSIP (títulos valores subyacentes)
Pay Date: CUSIP (títulos valores subyacentes)
Amount in USD to pay by CEDEARs: 30
Ex Date: 21/3/2023
Marker: None

Comment: Are you getting an error when reading the second PDF? Can you please share that if so.